# Alternative for windows store app WebView

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, webview, windows-store-apps

As you know, WebView is good to render HTML elements but it not work well with Flash. I have a website developed for a Totem enviroment to run as Kiosk mode in Windows 8.1, so i create a simple Windows App rendering this site in a WebView and associate with a Kiosk User. It worked fine but i forgot that the site has a flash animation that is called when the Totem isnt touched for 5 minutes.

Is there some option as alternative to the WebView? Something like the WebBrowser component in the mobile?

Comment: Flash isn't supported on Windows Phone. I don't know how your website works, but one alternative could be to rewrite the HTML code in your app to prevent the Flash animation from starting

Comment: To add to what KooKiz said, you could render the app as a video and simply replace instances of the flash animation with the video in certain instances.

Comment: I've also been looking for capable alternative in UWP, the only thing I found is [Cef](https://bitbucket.org/chromiumembedded/cef)